# How to get data from external USB device to android application?

Tags: android

i need functionality like..connect android device to external usb device using RS232 interface.
also receiving / fetching data from external USB device to my application.  this type functionality possible in android ? which step follows for this type of functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly: however, this will probably let you do what you want.

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10585

Its a combination USB host controller and Android API that uses the ADB protocol to pass data. Alternatively, you can also look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/microbridge/

Which needs an Arduino and doesn't appear to be that cleanly integrated but should also do what you want.

Comment: Hello Femi , now android 3.1 and 2.3.4 release and supported USB external device , so my functionality is possible using android USB api.

Comment: That is true: the Accessory API is now available so that will work for 2.3.4 and 3.1. If you however want to support the millions of existing 2.0/2.1/2.2/2.3.0 devices that probably won't ever get upgraded (I'm looking at Samsung here) the Accessory API is not sufficient.

Comment: Thanks.. it's not working another android device not major problem. but its work on 2.3.4 and 3.1 than it's useful for my requirement. so any help or details regarding this functionality than please send us details.

Comment: All the information is in the Accessory API documentation, at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html